# VGA not working but HDMI and DVI-D are working perfectly

Tags: motherboard, hdmi, vga, amd-radeon, dvi

I installed Windows 11 than Windows 10 on a newly built PC and the VGA output gives no signal on either of them, but the HDMI and DVI-D output are working perfectly.

This issue is also present in BIOS, VGA isn't working there and the two others are.

If I open up Windows Settings > System > Display, and connect all the three monitors, the HDMI and the DVI-D monitors are displayed, but the VGA monitor isn't, even if I press "detection", the monitor is not detected.

I bought this PC's parts and built it together by myself, and then installed all the necessary driver software with the motherboard's installer CD. And I haven't plugged in and out the VGA cable from the connector while the PC was powered on, so it's not like it went wrong because of such a silly reason I'm sure...

Is this problem related to the motherboard, the built-in video card in the processor or anything else?

The PC's parts:
AMD Ryzen 3 Pro 4350G
ASRock B450M PRO4
Crucial Ballistix RAM 16GB (2x8GB)

Comment: It could always simply be broken (even when newly purchased).

Comment: I believe those ASRock motherboards may have a BIOS setting that switches the video output to on-board graphics. Perhaps check for that?

Comment: Yes, i believe this is it. Let me know if this works and i'll provide it as an answer to your question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVYZRtqY8cI

Comment: @Mastaxx I have tried it on another but almost the same ASRock motherboard and it didn't work at all, and I tried this motherboard with the exact same but other CPU and it worked perfectly. So according to Daniel B it is probably broken, I've already given it back to check it.